# Reducing and plotting 3d point cloud to a 3d heat map in python?

Tags: python, visualization, heatmap, plotly-python

I'm working with a 3D set of (x, y, time) data. I'm trying to generate a heatmap of the (x,y) data over time in a smooth 3D heatmap. Plotly is preferred, but I'll take what I can get.

Data is of this form:

```
data_df = pd.DataFrame([(0,0,0),(1,1,1),(2,2,2),(1.1,1.2,1.4)], columns=['time','x','y'])
```

This is close to what I'm looking for (this was done in mathematica):
[image: example output]

For a bonus, I want to have an image (flat map) at the bottom of the plotting volume, as described in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60685749/python-plotly-how-to-add-an-image-to-a-3d-scatter-plot)

I've also considered a series of flat heatmaps at even intervals, which is less than ideal but I think would work enough to get the idea across. Unfortunately the only way I can figure to do that is as in the above described post, which doesn't seem optimal for this.

**Update:** Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25286811/how-to-plot-a-3d-density-map-in-python-with-matplotlib) I was able to generate the following: [image: this image] which is exactly what I'm looking for, however it is rendered in mayavi. I'm looking specifically for plotly due to other system integrations & plotting other information (map) on the same volume.