# How to draw a 2D layout (or shape) on a 3D Projection for Plotly_go?

Tags: python, plotly

I am trying to combine a 3D scatter plot with a 2D layout. Basically, I want to be able to project a football shot in 3D on a football pitch represented in 2D. I am able to do both individually, but not able to combine both solutions. Can someone help me?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dIo8.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YExHq.jpg)

Comment: It is possible but unless you provide some sample datasets, you likely won't get much help here. Do you have some data sets to work off of?

Comment: The 3D football pitch is plotted by plotly?

Comment: Provide the code that produces them indivisually.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Plotly: How to add an image to a 3D scatter plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60685749/python-plotly-how-to-add-an-image-to-a-3d-scatter-plot)